# Numpy max function fails when using Decimal values that include NaN

Tags: python, numpy

All is well when working with float values.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.max(1.2, np.nan)
>>> nan
```

But, when working with Decimal values...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import decimal as d 
>>> np.max([d.Decimal('1.2'), d.Decimal('NaN')])
>>> InvalidOperation: comparison involving NaN
```

Is there a way to get Decimal values with NaN's to play nicely?

Note:

- Python 2.7
- Numpy 1.6.2

Comment: This is probably a typo, but your should write `d.Decimal('1.2')` to take benefit of the decimal representation. `d.Decimal(1.2) == Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thanks, I've fixed it to read `d.Decimal('1.2')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hum ... if there is at least one *NaN*, the result is *NaN*.

Wrap in a function:

```
def my_max(arr):
    try:
        return np.max(arr)
    except d.InvalidOperation:
        return d.Decimal('NaN')
```

Not very sexy, though...

---

An alternative ... maybe ... as [`Decimal` allows to "un-trap" some exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial), returning a value instead of throwing an exception:

```
# change globally
>>> d.getcontext().traps[d.InvalidOperation] = 0
>>> np.max([d.Decimal('1.2'), d.Decimal('NaN')])
Decimal('NaN')
```

```
# use a context manager to change locally:
with d.localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.traps[d.InvalidOperation] = 0
    np.max([d.Decimal('1.2'), d.Decimal('NaN')])
```

Comment: Not very robust either - what happens if you get an InvalidOperation for a different reason?

Comment: @MarkRansom I can't think of anything except a _NaN_ that might make `np.max` to throw an `InvalidOperation`. Have you some specific ideas ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Numpy so I'm not sure, but wouldn't a `None` for example throw the error? That's one case that's easy to get by accident.

Comment: @MarkRansom As a matter of fact, `None` is "transparent": `np.max([d.Decimal(1.2), None]) == d.Decimal(1.2)` . Other "strange" values (dictionary, objects, ...) produces unexpected results, but do not throws `InvalidOperation` exception.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry, I didn't make myself very clear: `InvalidOperation` belongs to `Decimal` not `numpy`. This is really comparing `Decimal('NaN')` to something else that triggers that exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to a NumPy array of data type `float`. Then all NumPy functions should work well:

```
import numpy as np
import decimal as d

print np.max(np.array([0, 1, d.Decimal('nan')], dtype='float'))
print np.nanmax(np.array([0, 1, d.Decimal('nan')], dtype='float'))
```

Output:

```
nan
1.0
```

Comment: Works well, however the result/output is of type `numpy.float64`. I suppose one could convert the result back to `Decimal`. Would this be inefficient?

Comment: @AtlasStrategic: Hm, the efficiency probably depends on your application. Converting huge arrays back and forth sounds inefficient to me, but for a few values it might be alright. Do you really need ```Decimal```? Can't you switch to NumPy completely?

Comment: @AtlasStrategic From my point of view, this is *not* a question of efficiency. Converting from `Decimal` to _float_ and back, make you loose _all_ the benefits of using decimal representation. So the whole thing depend on your _need_ for `Decimal`. `Decimal(float(Decimal('1.2'))) == Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: I agree. (I just noticed that the question slightly changed to ```d.Decimal('1.2')```, thus exploiting the benefits of ```Decimal```.)